# Autowire String parameter in symfony

Tags: php, symfony

How can I wire a String parameter in Symfony 3.4?

I have simple service and I want to wire a `url` parameter specified in `parameters.yml`:

```
namespace AppBundle\Service;

use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

class PythonService {

    private $logger;
    private $url;

    /**
     * @param LoggerInterface $logger
     * @param String $url
     */
    public function __construct(LoggerInterface $logger, String $url) {
        $this->logger = $logger;
        $this->url = $url;
    }
}
```

My `service.yml` looks like:

```
AppBunde\Services\PythonService:
    arguments: ['@logger', '%url%']
```

But I am getting error:

```
Cannot autowire service "AppBundle\Service\PythonService": argument "$url" of method "__construct()" is type-hinted "string", you should configure its value explicitly.
```

I tried also manually specify parameters:

```
AnalyticsDashboardBunde\Services\PythonService:
    arguments:
        $logger: '@logger'
        $url: '%session_memcached_host%'
```

This gives me following error:

```
Invalid service "AppBundle\Services\PythonService": class "AppBundle\Services\PythonService" does not exist.
```

Comment: `AnalyticsDashboardBunde`, `AppBundle` which is correct?

Comment: As mentioned in a now deleted answer, just change Services to Service in your original service definition and all should be okay.  And spell AppBundle correctly.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

First, you have a typo in `AppBundle\Services\PythonService` (Services <> Service).

Then, string <> String. No uppercase in php.

---

You can bind an argument to a certain parameter/service:

**service.yml:**

```
services:
    _defaults:
        bind:
            $memcacheHostUri: '%session_memcached_host%'
```

**Service class: (have to be the same var name as specified ^)**

```
public function __construct(LoggerInterface $logger, string $memcacheHostUri)
```

**Controller action:**

```
public function myAwesomeAction(PythonService $pythonService)
{
    $pythonService->doPythonStuffs();
}
```

With this solution, if you create others services which need the `memecacheHostUri`, it will be autowired for these services too.

Resources:

[Argument binding](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container.html#binding-arguments-by-name-or-type)

Answer (score 0):

```
    //    services.yml
    app.python_service:
    class: AppBundle\Service\PythonService
    arguments:
        $logger: '@monolog.logger.request'
        $url: 'link'
    public: true

     //   in controller
    //use container:
    $pS = $this->container->get('app.python_service');
```

Comment: Using container is not recommended, inject dependencies instead.

Comment: just `public: true` helped. Thanks

Comment: No.  This works but is not the correct way to do.  It only works because Services was changes to Service.  And don't pull stuff from the container.  Sad that the correct answer was incorrectly deleted.