# symfony 4 autowire concern in __contruct

Tags: symfony

This is my very simple class, in Symfony 4 :

```
namespace App\Controller;

class T_contact
{
    public $email;
    public $name;
    /**
     * Constructor.
     *
     * @param string $email
     * @param string $name

     */
    public function __construct( $email, $name) {
        $this->email = $email;
        $this->name = $name;
    }
```

But i always get :
Cannot autowire service "App\Controller\T_contact": argument "$email" of method "__construct()" **has no type-hint**, you should configure its value explicitly.

I tried :
"...__construct (string $email, string $name)"
but I'm getting almost the same message except : 
"... **is type-hinted "string"**,you should configure...

I dont understand.
Any clue welcome...

Comment: Maybe your question is duplicated, look here : [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51672970/autowire-string-parameter-in-symfony](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51672970/autowire-string-parameter-in-symfony)

Comment: The problem is that autowire is trying to automatically make T_conact ins a service.  Which of course it is not.  Move T_contact into a directory such as Entity and then exclude the entity directory in your services.yaml file.

Comment: How does your `config.yml`/`services.yaml` look like?

Comment: It's the one coming from the skeleton project, but I dont know how to paste it here (too long)... :(

Comment: Moving the file into src/Entity did the trick ! But I'm not sure why... My file is not an Entity I think... Thx anyway, Cerad, you save my day ;-)

Comment: It worked because the Entity directory is already excluded in the out of the box services.yaml file.  You can adjust your services file to explicitly exclude T_contact regardless of where it is.  This is actually a very important concept to understand.  You will run into the same problem over and over until your understand why.  And while T_contact is not a Doctrine entity, it does act like a general entity.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot autowire strings because Symfony desn't know which one to inject. Services are autowired via their Class or Interface which serves as an identifier, but with parameters (int, strings and arrays), Symfony cannot guess which ones you want to inject. That's why you get the error message `...you should configure its value explicitly.`

Therefore you need to specify them manually in your services.yml

example:

```
  App/Controller/T_contact:
      arguments:
          $email: 'your_email'
          $name: 'your_name'
```

Additional remark: a best practice is to CamelCase your class name and if it is a controller suffix it with the term `Controller` (i.e. TContactController)

Comment: Thanks for your advices.
About the case : I prefer my entities to stick to the table names. T_contact is its MSSQL name. The next dev wont ask me questions.
I understand what you mean, but my class is not a service. Why should I add anything in services.yml ?
I'm a confirmed Drupal 7/8 dev, but I begun pure Symfony 5 **days** ago. Cant we use simple classes like this one ? 
Right now, I moved it into src/Entity, and changed its namespace. Everything works so far, but I dont understand why something is allowed in src/Entity while it's not in src/Controller ??

Comment: Ultimately I will use real Entities to connect to my database, but I'm just testing things in S4, for creating a REST API...

Comment: Wait, so your T_contact class in an entity and not a controller. Entities in symfony are not services, but model objects representing your database data model. So you need to instantiate entities with `new T_contact($email, $name);`. Controllers on the other side are part of the MVC pattern: they control the link between the view and the model (and other services you may use).